# Java logical error:keeps running same menu

Tags: java

```
package java_program;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Stock {

    String Path, company;

    public Stock(String Path, String company) {

        this.Path = Path;
        this.company = company;

    }

    public void blackHammer() throws Exception {

        BufferedReader csv = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Path));

        String row;

        while ((row = csv.readLine()) != null) {


            String[] data = row.split(",");

            String date = data[0];

            float openPrice = Float.parseFloat(data[1]), highPrice = Float.parseFloat(data[2]), lowPrice = Float.parseFloat(data[3]), 
            closePrice = Float.parseFloat(data[4]);

            System.out.println("Black Hammer Pattern of " + this.company + " in the past year:");


            if ((closePrice < openPrice) && ((highPrice-openPrice) < (openPrice-closePrice)/2) && (((closePrice-lowPrice)/5 < (openPrice-closePrice)) && (
                (openPrice-closePrice) < ((closePrice-lowPrice)/2)))) {

                System.out.println("Pattern Found: " + date);

            }
        }
        csv.close();

    }

}
```

```
package java_program;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java_program.Stock;

public class IS3230_YourID_Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Scanner abc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] arr = {"", "Microsoft", "Tesla", "HSBC"};

        String[] file = {"", "MSFT.csv", "TSLA.csv", "HSBC.csv"};

        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Please choose the company you want to analyze:");

            System.out.println("1 - Microsoft");
            System.out.println("2 - Tesla");
            System.out.println("3 - HSBC");
            System.out.println("0 - Exit the program");

            int c = abc.nextInt();

            Stock ob;

            switch(c){
                case 0:
                System.out.println("Thank you for using our stock analyzer: Bye");
                break;

                case 1:
                ob = new Stock(file[1], arr[1]);
                break;

                case 2:
                ob = new Stock(file[2], arr[2]);
                break;

                case 3:
                ob = new Stock(file[3], arr[3]);
                break;

                default:
                System.out.println("Error input");
                break;
            }
      
        }
    }

}
```

Error;

nomatter what I input to the program, it keeps running the menu in
IS3230_YourID_Demo file

```
Please choose the company you want to analyze:
1 - Microsoft
2 - Tesla
3 - HSBC
0 - Exit the program

no analysis result can be shown
```

the desired result is to show the date that matches the pattern

```
if ((closePrice < openPrice) && ((highPrice-openPrice) < (openPrice-closePrice)/2) && (((closePrice-lowPrice)/5 < (openPrice-closePrice)) && (
            (openPrice-closePrice) < ((closePrice-lowPrice)/2)))) {

            System.out.println("Pattern Found: " + date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `blackHammer` method at all. Also, the `break` statements will break out of the `switch` but not the loop. So the loop is infinite.

Comment: how can i break the while(true)?

Answer (score 0):

After you set `ob` in each of the cases, before the `break` add the following line:

```
ob.blackHammer();
```

In the `0` case, add a `return` instead of the `break` to exit the program.

So your cases should look like:

```
switch(c){
  case 0:
    System.out.println("Thank you for using our stock analyzer: Bye");
    return;

  case 1:
    ob = new Stock(file[1], arr[1]);
    ob.blackHammer();
    break;

  case 2:
    ob = new Stock(file[2], arr[2]);
    ob.blackHammer();
    break;

  case 3:
    ob = new Stock(file[3], arr[3]);
    ob.blackHammer();
    break;

  default:
    System.out.println("Error input");
    break;
}
```

Comment: problem still occur @holtc

Comment: Sorry, idk why my edit didn't save with the `ob.blackHammer();` being called, updated now

Comment: Sorry , still no no analysis result can be shown @holtc

Comment: That error, `no analysis result can be shown`, isn't anywhere in the code you've posted above

Comment: If you are seeing `no analysis result can be shown` in the console output, then I can't help you figure out that error because that output is not coming from the above code that you have posted. Is there any more code that is being used that you haven't posted?

Comment: the above code is all of my program. here is the question that I try to solve https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/requirement-given-three-csv-files-trading-data-different-companies-need-write-java-program-q61880299

Comment: Don't know what to tell you, if you're seeing `no analysis result can be shown`, that isn't in the code above.

Comment: The output should be showing the date that matches the pattern.